# How to protect a Firebase Node depending on sibling Node?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I need to implement some rules in Firebase to protect my data.

Let's say I have node **a** and node **b**. The structure is as follows:

```
{
    a:
    [
        a1: {uid: 123},
        a2: {uid: 321},
        a3: {uid: 567}
    ],
    b:
    [
        a1: {data: 'foo.bar'},
        a2: {data: 'foo.bar'},
        a3: {data: 'foo.bar'}
    ]
}
```

As in the example above, the *child nodes* of **a** are the *keys* of node **b**. How can I restrict the access to **data** of node **b** depending on the **uid** of node **a**?

For example. The *user* with **uid** 123 in the node **a**, his key is **a1**, so, in node **b** only can retrieve data from child node **a1** (b -> a1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a rule system like this would match your requirement:

```javascript
{
  "rules": {
    "b": {
      "$key": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == root.child('a').child($key).child('uid').val()",
        ".write": "auth !== null"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this example, `$key` is a [`$location` variable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#location) that matches any key under the list of node `b`.

We can then use this `$key` variable to match the [current user's `auth.uid`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#auth) to the `uid` of the corresponding node under `a`, using [`root.child()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#root).

The result is that this will only grant read access to a child under `b` if the `uid` of the corresponding child with the same key under `a` matches the current user's `uid`.